# VBScript code to do math based on folder contents

Tags: vbscript

I could use some help in troubleshooting my code, which should run a report based on files in a folder, which meet certain criteria, read specific lines from those files and sum all the read values. And do some math later on.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
relativePath = wshShell.CurrentDirectory
Set ReportPath = objFSO.GetFolder(relativePath & "\KPI_STATS\")
count = 0
```

Now I'd like to check each file's filename in `ReportPath` if it matches current month...

```
For Each file In ReportPath.files
    If instr(LCase(file.name), LCase(Right("0" & DatePart("m",Now),2))) > 0 Then
        for i=0 to n
```

SIDENOTE: Now I don't understand why if I run `msgbox(file)` for testing only it gives me whole path to the folder with filename instead of filename only.

(let's continue)...and when it does, it should read only 14th line of text (last line and there are only numbers in it) of each file and store it in variable. I use `Split` for reading certain lines from files and arrays to hold read values but I can use as well something like sum = sum + sum(n-1).

```
             a = Split(objFSO.OpenTextFile(file, ForReading).ReadAll, vbCrLf)
             For j = 14
                 If UBound(a) = j Then
```

And now I'd like to write those values to separate Arrays

```
                     ar(i) = Array(a(j))
                 End If
              Next
        next
        count = count + 1
    End If
Next
```

I think I will manage to add and divide all the values as soon as I have all arrays in place but there i a problem. It doesn't work :'(

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is a little bit too much to digest.  Can you break down your code and indicate *specifically* what's not working?

Comment: `a = Split(objFSO.OpenTextFile(file, ForReading).ReadAll, vbCrLf)`

`For j = 14`

                      ` If UBound(a) = j Then `

`ar(i) = Array(a(j))`

                    `Next`
            `next`

Comment: What is that supposed to be?  I'm no detective.  Can you be more clear?  What is the problem?

Comment: The first obvious problem is `For j = 14` is not a valid loop statement.

Comment: How *exactly* does it "not work"? What result do you get, and how does it differ from the result you expect? Also, do you want to read the *last* line of each file, or the *14th* line? Even if all your files have only 14 lines there's a semantic difference between the two approaches.

Comment: It is simply not working. Is there a easy way to read 14th line of each file and sum values into one variable?